# Remove everything after dot and overwrite in same file

Tags: bash, sed

The file contents similar to below

```
abc.w.f.com
asdff.d.f.com
..........
```

I want to remove everything after dot and changes should be overwrite in same file

```
abc
asdff
```

Tried below , but this requires redirect to another file, which i dont want

```
sed "s/\..*//" Filename  > File2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't redirect to the same file: the obvious problem with `sed "s/\..*//" Filename > Filename` is that the shell opens `Filename` for writing (and overwrites it) before the file is read by `sed`.

You'd need to redirect output to a different file, delete the original file, and then rename the newly created file the same as the original. Sed, Perl and AWK can do this for you:

- `sed -i`
- `perl -i`
- `awk -i inplace`

Alternatively, you can use `sponge`:

- `sed "s/\..*//" Filename | sponge Filename`

`sponge` keeps buffering what it receives from standard input, and only then writes it to `Filename`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-i`:

```
sed -i 's/\..*$//' Filename
```

> **-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]**
>   edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)